# Advice on using a listview as a child in an expandable listview

Tags: android, listview, nested, expandablelistview

I have an Expandable ListView

```
<ExpandableListView
     android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1" >
 </ExpandableListView>
```

and a custom layout for the group

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:tag="tank" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:text="123" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1000" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and a custom layout for the child

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:text="This is the number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="3.38672" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hrzntl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#696969" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Strap"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="height" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="volume" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hrzntl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#696969" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and a custom layout for listView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

How can I go about populating this with a custom class extending BaseExpandableListAdapter?

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}}
```

Comment: plenty of tutorials on android.developer.com. giyf, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LayoutInflater` to inflate and return the layout you want for the group in `getGroupView()` and the layout you want for the children in `getChildView()`.